# Stacktrace begins with 0x0

Tags: unix, stack-trace, callstack

I am currently analysing an odd callstack that starts from 0x00000000. How is it actually possible for ELF ring3 application? It has a default 0x8048000 as entry point.

Thank you.

Comment: I have got a wrong core dump for a file.

Comment: What is more, it could have happened because of missing libraries for GDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a missing library for GDB, so the debugger mapped its call as 0x0.