# Why end of the stack is null?

Tags: c++, c, stack, stack-trace, coredump

I was trying to figure out a crash in a application. The crash occurs on stress testing. At the time of crash the `VIRT` is around 19 Gigs and `RES` is 2.1 Gigs. This is to mentioned that the system has a physical memory of 3 Gigs and swap space of 5 Gigs.

Where the application crash, the core dump does not give any symbols in stack strace even if correct symbols are loaded. But I notice a strange behaviour, the bottom of the call stack is null.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00002adaea9df74d in ?? ()
#1  0x00002aacc94ff700 in ?? ()
#2  0x00000000004f9023 in ?? ()
#3  0x00002aae2b8054e0 in ?? ()
#4  0x00002aae6d9420a0 in ?? ()
#5  0x00002aacc94ff700 in ?? ()
#6  0x0000000000486312 in ?? ()
#7  0x00002aae2b8054e0 in ?? ()
#8  0x00002aacc94ff700 in ?? ()
#9  0x00002aacc94ff440 in ?? ()
#10 0x00002aae6d9420a0 in ?? ()
#11 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

What could be the possible reason for this? Is it because the stack is corrupted?

Comment: It might help if you tag your question with some of the technologies involved - e.g. programming language(s), os, etc.

Comment: Ok I will do it. :). But I have a past history when people removing the programming language tags for same type of question.

Comment: @RituparnaKashyap they would remove tags if they don't make sense. For example, is your program in C++ **and** C?

Comment: Program is in c++ but all the libs are in c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302630/stacktrace-begins-with-0x0 take a look at

Comment: @tim-oleksii : Then it should be true for all crash. When there is a deliberate crash it bottom of the call stack does not point of NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely option is that something trashed your call stack: that can explain both why your debugger is showing garbage and why your application crashed. I would suggest to try running your code under [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: We do valgrind test, with low load. Every thing is fine. We are getting this crash under heavy load, and that too after running for 2-3 days. If we profile the same with valgrind, it would take ages to get the test case.

Comment: Anyway we will try it though. Apart from this is there anything other/OS parameter that we can monitor.

Comment: Your compiler might have hardening/security options to protect the stack that should make you app segfault at the point where the callstack is trashed. That can help you with debugging this.